# 'like' keyword use in mysql triggers

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

i want to use "like" in triggers 
i have two table 't1', 't2'

i want to check t1.col1 contain t2.col1 data.

i tried some but i facing issue when passing value with in like

i used;

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`myuser`@`%` TRIGGER `t1_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set NEW.col2 = IFNULL((select distinct 1 from t2 where new.col1 like **t2.col1%** ),0);
END
```

now i am confused which value inset into BOLD text

Comment: i want to check t1.col1 containing t2.col1 data or not;
if its contain return 1 if not return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
select distinct 1 from t2 where new.col1 LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.col1, '%')
```